# AjaxFileupload upload more files than allowed

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I'm using AjaxFileUpload from Ajaxtoolit in normal asp.net page to upload files,I have set MaximumNumberofFiles to 1 because I just want user upload one file per time.

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload_UploadComplete" ThrobberID="MyUploadingSong" ContextKeys="SongUploading" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" runat="server" AutoStartUpload="true"/>
```

So when user click on browse it can select just one file to upload, but the problem is after that file is uploaded, user can select another file and add another file to list, How can I disable the upload button after user select one file?

Answer (score 3):

There are no built-in control capabilities for that, but you can find the upload button on a page and hide it (using jQuery)

```js
$(".ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton").hide();
```

Note that Upload button is a div, so "disabling" it will get no effect.

You can also remove the button from the DOM:

```
$(".ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton").remove();
```